# What is the explanation to the ending of the Japanese movie Suicide Club?

Tags: plot-explanation, suicide-club

Who are the group of children in the ending of the movie [Suicide Club](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suicide_Club_%28film%29)?
Whose children are they and why are they trying to teach everyone the lesson of being connected to themselves as they are to others?